# How to close-in on no-stack-trace crashes in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, debugging, crash

We built a huge app with 10's of classes and 100's of methods.

In some stress test - the app crashes (the test is moving between tabs and views very quickly like crazy)

The app just exits, no stack trace, no data from NSZombie's, no data at all. No sigabrt, no bad_access.... nothing!!

How do you close-in on this kind of crash?

Thanks

Comment: Exclude one class at a time, and narrow it down I guess. With no stack-trace...

Comment: When you tether the device that crashed into Xcode, and open Organizer->Devices, do you see a crash log in there?